# NodeJs: Extract data from particular tag from body of response

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I get data from only tags from http get request's response body in node js. Can I get something like findByElementName or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

If you looking to parse HTML with node js, look at this if you want to do it with XPATH
https://github.com/goto100/xpath

Or https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio if you want to use selector like in JQUERY